# Custom Adminhtml Grid + ORM Column Issue

Tags: adminhtml, grid

When creating a custom adminhtml grid, I've run into a very strange issue when modifying the column type in the database from for instance Date to varchar:

Initially - works 100% (as type Date in the table):

```
$this->addColumn('credit_date',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Credit<br/>Date'),
            'index' => 'credit_date',
            'width' => '5%',
            'type' => 'date'
        )
    );
```

Updated to varchar in the table:

```
$this->addColumn('credit_date',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Credit<br/>Date'),
            'index' => 'credit_date',
            'width' => '5%'
        )
    );
```

After a full re-index & cache refresh, refreshing the page now only displays the column titles and no records. I found that if I rename the column name in the table & magento, it then displays 100%.

What is the reasoning behind this strange behvaior?

Comment: The table schema is cached even when cache is disabled. Maybe that's it. You need to clear the cache.

Comment: @Marius - I did refresh all caches, flushed Magento cache & cache storage as well as JS/CSS cache on top of reindexing all of the tables. The issue persists through this.

Comment: After changing the column type, did you log out? The problem might appear if you have the grid parameters stored in session.

Comment: That was indeed the issue @Marius, session persist. Thanks, you can post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, the error appears because the grid uses `saveParametersInSession` set to `true`. The values stored in the session conflict with the database values and column names.
Solution: Log out and re login in the admin panel.